# Best way to iterate through every row for following case?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column called 'primary_role' that contains information about the user's role/account type in the organization. There is a corresponding column with the same name as the value in their 'primary_role' column. I need to extract the data from this column.

For example a row with a value of 'Read-Only Account' under primary_role column, will have data in another column called 'Read-Only Account'. A 'Manager', will have data in the 'Manager' column, while the 'Read-Only Account' column will be blank for this person. Just a note, the value stored in these columns are string interpretations of a dictionary like data. I'm using ast.literal_eval to convert that string to a dictionary.

What I need to do is extract the data under the matching user role specific column and store that information in a separate column called prop_id or something similar. There is a redundant string value stored in this data that I'm removing using isdigit().

Here's a sample code for what I'm doing with just one row:

```
role_col = users_df.iloc[0]['primary_role'] # primary role column value
ls = ast.literal_eval(users_df[role_col].iloc[0])['organization'] # feed role column value as column name to get value, convert to actual dictionary
cleaned = [ int(x) for x in ls if x.strip().isdigit() ] # returns only numbers (some users manage multiple properties)
```

My first thought was to create a for loop using users_df.iterrows() and work from there, but this seems a bit too much considering there are over 5000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to use the apply function to create a new column based on the values of the `primary_role` column and the corresponding role-specific column. You can write a custom function that takes a row as an input and returns the cleaned data from the matching column. For example:

```
import ast

def get_prop_id(row):
  role_col = row['primary_role']
  ls = ast.literal_eval(row[role_col])['organization']
  cleaned = [int(x) for x in ls if x.strip().isdigit()]
  return cleaned

users_df['prop_id'] = users_df.apply(get_prop_id, axis=1)
```

The apply function will apply your custom function to each row and assign the result to the new column.